# Is Windows safe for using Tor?

Tags: anonymity, windows

Is it dangerous to use Tor in Windows if:

- I have all the latest updates that protect from Etherblue exploit.
- my PC is not infected with any viruses.
- I does not have any anti-viruses that log my activity.
- all telemetry turned off.
- have hostfile lines like 127.0.0.1 so that Windows cannot send logs to Microsoft.

What more can I do to run Tor in Microsoft Windows and be sure that I'm safe?

Comment: What are you trying to be safe *from*?

Comment: Your question in its current form is quite unclear. Your system is not safe from being stolen, your system can have a keylogger which logs all strokes and sends them to someone, someone can render your system being unusable etc. Please be more specific what you mean by being safe.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot be safe regardless of what safeguards you try to set up.
The reason is simply because windows is closed software, and Microsoft is in control of it - not the end-user, you cannot verify what is happening on the OS, even if you try the options you mention, there is simply no guarantee on such a OS.

The same applies to all 3rd party software you run on top of it, antivirus, firewalls and so on, it just cannot be determined to be safe if it is closed source software.